# Seeking embeddable web-based maps

Tags: software-recommendations, embeddable-web-maps

Some of the ones I'm familiar with (in no particular order):

Google Maps (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

Bing Maps (http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/)

Yahoo Maps (http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/)

MapQuest (http://developer.mapquest.com/)

OpenLayers (http://openlayers.org/)

WorldWind Java (http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/)

OpenMap (http://www.openmap.org/)

Are there others that I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

Don't forget [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org). There are many map viewers that can display the OSM data. I.e. [JMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer), [MapPanel](http://mappanel.sourceforge.net/) and [JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html) for Java applications. At least the last one can also display Google Maps in your application.